# Sorting integer elements of a vector

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting, vector

I would like to calculate the median of elements stored in a vector

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

 ....
 ....
 ....

vector<int> trmVa;
int size;
int median;
int trimVal;

trmVa.push_back(trimVal);
size = trmVa.size();
sort(trmVa.begin(), trmVa.end()); //I am having troubles here!!!!

if(size % 2) {
  median = (trmVa[size/2 - 1] + trmVa[size/2]) /2;
  printf("Module %d \n\n \t Median = %d\n", mod, median); 
}else {
   median = trimVa[size/2];
   printf("Module %d \n\n \t Median = %d\n", mod, median);
}
```

Error: operator- not defined for vector >::iterator algo.h:722. I appreciate the help.

Comment: @tuğrulbüyükışık He is using std::sort

Comment: The call to `sort` looks fine. But you could use [std::nth_element](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/nth_element) if all you want is the median. In fact, your title should reflect what you want to do, not how you think it should be done.

Comment: This [compiles for me](http://ideone.com/ilNpj). after fixing variable names. Show your real code.

Comment: @fclopez: Have any of your other questions been answered satisfactorily?  Consider marking some of them as correct.

Answer (score 3):

You can solve this problem more efficiently using [std::nth_element](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/nth_element). This will only do a partial sorting of the vector, and has linear complexity. This is an example for an odd-sized vector:

```
size_t midIndex = trmVa.size()/2;
nth_element(trmVa.begin(), tmrVa.begin() + midIndex, trmVa.end());
```

the median value is

```
trmVa[midIndex];
```

You can easily extend this to cover even-sized vectors.